# Custom chart type with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts

Is it possible to draw completely different chart types then predefined?

I searched through the existing types and was unable to find a suitable one.

In general, I need to build smth

like a "bar and wisher" candle (like Excel has)
but with numbers on top and bottom plates (deviation errors)

Thanx.

PS:[fugures like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIDHg.jpg)
 so, chart line comes between 2 integers and given error related to each interes

Comment: Box and whisker. Check out [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/).

Comment: Unfortunatelly bar and wisker chart provide required information, related to neighboring points (on Y-Axis)